# Is there anyway to move apps and data from regular android phone to xiaomi?

Tags: xiaomi

Helium back up doesn't seem to work for xiaomi at all.

Anyone ever did restore helium back up to xiaomi?

What are the other alternatives? Google play restore doesn't seem to work either.

Note: I do NOT need to back up the APK. What I mainly want is to back up content of chat applications like wechat, whatsapp, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an app called Mi Mover which helps to transfer data from one Android Phone to a Mi phone. Users can refer [Xiaomiadvices](http://xiaomiadvices.com/) for download links and tutorial on [how to transfer data using Mi Mover app](http://xiaomiadvices.com/mi-mover-apk-download/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en). It works on both other Android mobiles as well as Xiaomi mobiles.

This [link](http://en.miui.com/thread-3998-1-1.html) will help you to install google play store and other apps.

If installed google apps not working then refer this [link](http://en.miui.com/thread-22576-1-1.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, ends up in very low quality posts review queue and more often than not, are recommended for deletion simply because the post fails to being helpful once the content behind the link fails to remain available. Consider quoting the relevant parts from the links into this answer to make the latter self-sufficient.

Comment: And do you need to root your phone?

Comment: @J.Chang: No root.